# Visual Studio 2022 build failed, but Visual studio 2019 build succeeded

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I have a solution with many c# and c++ projects, but I'm interested in 2 of them: let's call them C++ proj1 and C# proj2 and proj2 is referensing to proj1.
Solution builds succesfully in vs2019, but build failed in vs2022.
When I try to build the solution in vs2022 I see the following in the build output:

**Warning:**

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3274: failed to resolve reference "C:\...\Debug\proj1.dll",because it was built using the platform ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2". This is a later version than the current target platform (".NETFramework,Version=v4.5").
```

And right after that I get the **error:**

```
C:\...\proj2\MyClass.cs(1,7,1,22): error CS0246: Could not find type or namespace name "proj1" (possibly missing using directive or assembly reference).
```

But there is no such error during design (in vs 2022) and no such waraning and error in vs 2019 during the build.

I understand that the error is that an older framework version targeting a newer framework version. But then I don't understand why in vs 2019 the solution builds successfully.

How can I resolve this build issue in vs 2022?

Comment: Make the Framework versions the same.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The С++ project (proj1) target framework version wasn't set. I set .net framework v4.5 in .vcxproj file and it helped to solve the problem with the build in vs 2022. Do I understand correctly that by default when I build an assembly, vs2019 setting target framework version 4.5, and vs2022 setting target framework version 4.7.2?

Comment: I've never had a project without the .NET version set. Not sure whether that's a C++ thing but I don't use C++ so I can't say.